# How to transpile es6 npm modules in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular 6 application am importing a npm module (pseudo-localization ) developed on es6 due to which after the build, the vendor.js  shows error in IE 11.

so how can i transpile particular npm module ?

Comment: You should include the module(s), how you are referencing them in your project, and *all* the error details in your question.

Comment: I have imported import 
 /* { localize } from 'pseudo-localization' */ npm which contains arrow functions. so after built vendor file has error in it

Comment: what is the ``target`` in your tsconfig.json ?

Comment: "target": "es5", in angular transpile happens only for custom modules not npm, so the vendor.js just merging all npm into a file as vendor.js